# Windows SMTP Relay Server to add BCC to all emails

Tags: email, windows-server-2008-r2, email-server, smtp

I'm looking for a Windows based SMTP Relay Server which allows me to add a specific BCC field to all outgoing emails that relayed through this server.

The reason for such requirement is that we need to track if the email is actually sent. We're sending our email to end users via our cooperate email server. Currently we're receiving complaint that our end users did not receive our emails, but we don't have access to the email server's log.

At the same time, our developers are using a specific library which doesn't allows adding BCC, or it's much more tedious to do so than replacing our SMTP Relay with one that add BCC.

Currently we're using IIS' SMTP Server as our relay.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is a technical query to resolve a social problem.  Ask your e-mail server admin's for access to the log to prove that the e-mail was sent.  Even adding a BCC to the outbound mail won't prove much, if it doesn't arrive, how do you know it didn't get eaten by some other server en route?  You need to read your corporate mail server logs.

Or, at the very least, just subscribe to your own mailing list with a couple of e-mail addresses and see if you get the mail when the mail is sent to your users.

Comment: Do you mind to elaborate more on the "subscribe to your own mailing list" and how does that differ from BCC? Doesn't that means adding more email into the TO list? Thanks

Comment: Btw, those mail are "Registration" emails, destined to single user only.

Comment: You send mail to users, make one of those users your e-mail address, and then you'll know if the mail got sent.  But either way, you should just ask to see the logs from your organisation's e-mail admin.

Comment: Isn't that the same as BCC? The reason I want to use BCC instead of TO, is now to show the tracking email address. Btw, those are external users, so I won't have access to their mail.

Comment: You're missing my point - to add a BCC you need to put another mail relay in place.  To subscribe to your own mails, just become a *user* of the site that sends mails, and then it'll send you one and you'll know if it works.  But all this is moot, you're missing the much wider point, these are technical solutions to a non-technical problem.  Talk to your mail admins, does your company want to fix this issue or not?  The way to fix it is to work together with your mail admins and trace the mail.

Comment: We need a relay anyway to buffer the delivery. I understand the social point. There's difficulty to that as the email server belongs to a diff department of our client, plus the security clearance to retrieve the log is too much hassle, further more frequent retrieval is even more difficult.

Comment: I can't say it any other way - adding another relay proves nothing.  You need the logs from the final relay.  The site isn't for discussion so I'll leave it there.